# Optimal way to convert an Array of Objects into an Array of Arrays containing Objects

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, typescript, for-loop

Take for example this extremely simplified Array of Objects:

```
[
    {
      createID: '1'
      // Many other properties...
    },
    {
      createID: '1'
      // Many other properties...
    },
    {
      createID: '1'
      // Many other properties...
    },
    {
      createID: '37'
      // Many other properties...
    },
    {
      createID: '37'
      // Many other properties...
    },
    {
      createID: '2'
      // Many other properties...
    },
    {
      createID: '2'
      // Many other properties...
    },
    {
      createID: '14'
      // Many other properties...
    },
  ];
```

Given this Array I then use the objects `createID` property to create an Array of Arrays containing Objects `[[{..},{..}], [{..}], ..n]`. This final format is required by the current front end framework I am using (Angular v6).

To accomplish this task I use the following code, where `tempArr` is an array like the example array provided above.

```
    let currentGroup: string = tempArr[0].createID;
    let tempGrouped: any[] = [];
    let childGroup: any[] = [];
    tempArr.forEach(item => {
      if (item.createID !== currentGroup) {
        tempGrouped.push(childGroup);
        childGroup = [];
        currentGroup = item.createID;
      }
      childGroup.push(item);
    });
    tempGrouped.push(childGroup);
```

This code works fine. However, I can't help but believe **there must be a more efficient and elegant way given the data to convert an Array of objects into an Array of Arrays containing objects.**

#### ***Update***

It is important to note that the `createID`'s *are only id's that signify which objects should be grouped together.* Therefore, they do not need to be numerically ordered by `createID`. In addition, the objects do come from the server "grouped" with their sibling objects (same `createID`) as you can see in the given example array provided.

Comment: If you could provide a stackblitz with a working example, it would be easier for us to provide working alternatives. :-)

Comment: More elegant? Use `for … of` instead of `.forEach`. More efficient? No, what you have is optimal.

Comment: Will your objects with identical IDs always be adjacent to each other?

Comment: @MarkMeyer, yes they will - see my update in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example has all identical IDs adjacent to each other. If that is guaranteed to always be the case, looping though and pushing to a new array is all you need. However if this isn't the case, your solution will fail to group items properly.  In that case using a hash table will allow you to still group by ID with same asymptotic complexity.

You can group your objects into a hash table object with keys created from `createdID`. This will let you group everything efficiently. Then just take the objects from the hash table:

```js
let arr = [{createID: '1'},{createID: '1'},{createID: '1'},{createID: '37'},{createID: '37'},{createID: '2'},{createID: '2'},{createID: '14'},];

let o = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
    (a[c.createID] || (a[c.createID] = [])).push(c)
    return a
}, {} )
// o is a an object with createID keys pointing to arrays of grouped objects
// just take the values
console.log(Object.values(o))
```

**Edit based on question edit**

Since the objects will already be grouped, there's not a better way than looping through. If you want an option that doesn't add the temp arrays, you can still use `reduce()`, which is essentially the same as your current solution, but maybe a little more self contained:

```js
let tempArr = [{createID: '1'},{createID: '1'},{createID: '1'},{createID: '37'},{createID: '37'},{createID: '2'},{createID: '2'},{createID: '14'},];

let r = tempArr.reduce((a, c, i, self) => {
    if (i === 0 || self[i-1].createID !== c.createID) 
        a.push([])
    a[a.length - 1].push(c)
    return a
}, [])

console.log(r)
```

Comment: A hash table is more complicated and not necessary when the groups are already in the right order. This is probably less efficient than what the OP currently uses.

Comment: @Bergi the OPs solution looks O(n**2) and depends on several unnecessary temp arrays. How is that simpler?

Comment: The OPs solution is linear, not `O(n²)`.

Comment: @Bergi my mistake I though they were grouping objects by id regardless of order-- it would be O(n**2) if it didn't depend on already grouped objects. With their current solution objects with the same ID that aren't adjacent end up in different arrays.

Comment: Yes, but it seems that is intended (as the OP claims their code is working). You could however edit your answer to say that looking up the group by id is more *robust* than relying on the order, with the same runtime complexity.

Comment: This is wonderful, although your second response does answer the question more specifically - I must admit I like how compact, simple, and robust your first response is using the hash table. Thank you for your response and time!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your array of data is stored into a variable called `data`:

```
  const result = data.reduce((acc, current) => {
    if (!acc.dictionary[current.createID]) {
      const createIdArray = [];
      acc.dictionary[current.createID] = createIdArray;
      acc.array.push(createIdArray);
    }

    acc.dictionary[current.createID].push(current);

    return acc;
  }, {array: [], dictionary: {}}).array;
```

This way, you'll loop only once on data, and it's efficient as we don't use filter or find (which would go through the whole array again and again).

Here's the output:

```
[
  [
    {
      createID: '1',
    },
    {
      createID: '1',
    },
    {
      createID: '1',
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      createID: '37',
    },
    {
      createID: '37',
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      createID: '2',
    },
    {
      createID: '2',
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      createID: '14',
    },
  ],
];
```

Here's a running demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-phbzug

**Summary:**

- The dictionary is self contained within the reduce function which means that as soon as the reduce is done, it'll be garbage collected
- Not relying on any external variables, easier to reason about and IMO a better practice
- This solution is more robust (the array doesn't need to be sorted) for ~ the same number of lines as OP's answer
- Clean: With the dictionary you know directly what you're accessing and it's really fast

Comment: Why use a dictionary? The groups already are in the right order.

Comment: Who tells you that the groups are in the "right order"? OP never said that. Plus, I'm handling the case where it's not, looping only once, and the reference to the dictionary is self contained within the reduce function which means that as soon as it's run, it'll be garbage collected. I don't see any problem here. That said, do you have a better solution to share? :)

Comment: OP says their solution is working so they seem to assume that the groups are ordered. Their current solution is looping only once as well, and probably quite faster. If you think that the dictionary approach is better (it may indeed), please edit your answer to state in which situations your code produces different results.

Comment: OP might be looping only once but it also rely on 3 "external" variables, which I would rather avoid. Then, OP solution is less robust as it assume that data are in a given order (which might be) but for as many lines you can get a more robust solution, so why not. It's not even more complicated to reason about. With the dictionary you know directly what you're accessing and it's really fast.

Comment: Please add that to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

you want to group by createID?

```
let grouped=tempArray
//first get uniq values
.filter((s,index)=>tempArray.findIndex(f=>f.createID==s.createID)==index)
//then, with the uniq values make a map       
.map(seg=>{  //with each uniq value, create an object with two properties
   return {
      createID:seg.createID,  //the key
      items:tempArray.filter(s=>s.createID==seg.createID) //An array with the values
   }
})
```

Comment: Using filter, findIndex and filter is not optimised.

Comment: true, it's elegant and allow the array of object can be unsorted, but sure there are a more efficiency method. I gooogle and in https://hackernoon.com/javascript-performance-test-for-vs-for-each-vs-map-reduce-filter-find-32c1113f19d7 we can see that filter and find are not so efficient

Comment: Without even talking about performance, just reading the first filter takes quite a lot of time.... plus it wouldn't even output what OP expect. Try to make a stackblitz :)